# Create new folder when create new User

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-signals

I'm using Allauth module for create accounts and signing in. But I'm also need to create a new directory for every user, who makes an account.
I know that I need to use Signals some how... But cant find a start point for that.
Am I need to create new model, view or whatever? Or what I need to do to complete this task?

Answer (score 1):

You need a [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/signals/#post-save) signal for the User model.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def create_folder(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if not created:  # if it's not a new object return
        return

    # do your stuff

post_save.connect(create_folder, sender=User)
```